# How to make the keyboard overlap a component?

Tags: react-native

The yellow component is a tabBar and it should be fixed to the bar, and the keyboard should overlay it when opened. And the red component should rise without decreasing its height. 
Already tried to use the KeyboardAvoidingView component, it did not work. But I think I used it incorrectly. Can anyone help me solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `AndroidManifest.xml` change

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

with

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```